# How can I set Timeout on this jQuery code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I've been trying to create a typing effect and I've found this code snippet which works perfectly. The only issue is that I need to set a delay of 6 seconds before it starts running and I am not able to do that.

The situation is that I have a number of slides and this text is on the first slide. So, basically I need it to start with a delay of 6 seconds after the first slide is played.

I've tried giving the function a name and setting Timeout on that as well as setting Timeout on the whole function and neither of them worked. I have tested quite a few other approaches that I thought would work and none of them worked. I am still not confident in jQuery and that might be why I cannot think of the proper solution.

```js
$.fn.typewriter = function () {
   this.each(function () {
      var c = $(this),
         b = c.html(),
         a = 0,
         d = 0;
      c.html("");
      var e = function () {
         if ("<" == b.substring(a, a + 1)) {
            var f = new RegExp(/<span class="instant"/),
               g = new RegExp(/<span class="clear"/);
            if (b.substring(a, b.length).match(f)) a += b.substring(a, b.length).indexOf("</span>") + 7;
            else if (b.substring(a, b.length).match(g)) d = a, a += b.substring(a, b.length).indexOf("</span>") + 7;
            else
               for (;
                  ">" != b.substring(a, a + 1);) a++
         }
         c.html(b.substring(d, a++) + (a & 1 ? "_" : ""));
         a >= b.length || setTimeout(e, 50 + 50 *
            Math.random())
      };
      e()
   });
   return this;
};

$(".terminal").typewriter();
```

Comment: A delay of 6 seconds from what? When the page loads? When a key is a pressed? Be more specific.

Comment: @MaxVoisard I editted the question and added more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
   typewriterFunction()
  }, 6000 );
};

function typewriterFunction() {
// Code for typing effect after first slide plays
}
```

Comment: Code only answers are generally considered low quality. Could you add an explanation to your answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
window.onload = function() {
   setTimeout(typewriterFunction, 6000)
};

function typewriterFunction() {
    // Code for typing effect after first slide plays
}
```

Comment: @Leila Weird. Is there some type of error message appearing in the Console? What is the actual behavior/output?

Comment: I don't remember the error unfortunately, since I changed the code. But I tried it with a different code snippet and it worked on page load, not with this one, though. And it still doesn't work when the slide is played back. Any ideas on that?

Comment: @Leila Sorry, I'm out of ideas.